# Sorting associated products (configurable) in 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have Magento 1.9.2 and a configurable product with size options (S,M,L,XL) those options are associated simple products. At the moment Magento is sorting the options by ID. Is there anyway to sort by a specified order that I give?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's a known bug in Magento 1.9.1 and afaik still not fixed as of 1.9.2.2. See linked question for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Last column on associated products is used for sorting. Called position

Comment: Thanks for coming back vback but I can't see that option in 1.9.2. Are you using the same version?