# sort associated products of a configureable product

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.2.1, sort

I have several configurable products with multiple associated products.  I want to sort the associated products in the drop down on the product page.  For example I have a size, I want to order them by 7/16, 9/16, 11/16...  etc.

I have ordered them in the attribute, and it doesn't change anything.  They remain sorted by "ID" no matter what I change.

Now, before you go marking this as a duplicate question....

I found this article - [Magento 1.9.1 configurable product attribute sorting](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45396/magento-1-9-1-configurable-product-attribute-sorting)
which states that it doesn't work for version 1.9.2.1

I found this article which strangely is marked as duplicate and refers back to the first article, which doesn't work for 1.9.2.1!  [Sorting associated products (configurable) in 1.9.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80283/sorting-associated-products-configurable-in-1-9-2)

So, how do I sort these attributes in my version?  Is this in a fix somewhere?

Comment: Seems like the second answer of the first link you posted works on 1.9.2 according to the comments